# How to integrate Highmap chart with angular 5 Application?

Tags: highcharts, angular5

I want to integrate highmap chart with an Angular 5 application. I have tried `angular-highchart` module but it's not working as expected.

[angular-highchat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts)

Let me know if you have any solution or any other way to integrate highmap.

Comment: I also faced same issue.

Comment: @SiddharthSarfale Have you got any solution for the same ?

Comment: No i didn't found any solution for this yet

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `highcharts-angular` package instead of mentioned above. There shouldn't be any problem with Highmaps implementation. Here the reference link to package and also the documentation, where everything is described very precisely and clear: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular